# How to retain the smell of frying green onions/scallions in cooked dish?

Tags: asian-cuisine, stir-fry

I have always loved the smell of frying green onions/scallions but was never able to retain the smell of it when the dish is done cooking.

I was in Singapore about 1.5 years ago and in a small food court, I enjoyed a plate of fried rice noodles and the aroma of the frying scallions was very much present which made the dish much better.

I was not able to replicate it at home, no matter when I put the scallions in, the aroma always disappeared at the end. The smell of it was quite strong in the dish I had and I have no idea how it is done.

Is there a trick to retain the smell of frying scallions? or maybe it's something else that producing the smell?

Comment: Are you taking into account that something in a food court will have taken at most 3 minutes to prepare; anything that would have taken longer will be pre-prepped, so your home version will have to be done in the same time for the onions to come out as they did it.

Comment: I have tried putting the green onions in at the last minute or stir frying everything (pre-prepped, cooked already) at once but nothing has worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were probably having a dish with [green onion oil](https://redhousespice.com/make-use-spring-onion-oil/), something I'd also recommend as a solution to the smell/taste you're looking for.  It remains aromatic for a couple weeks after you make a batch and bottle it. I make one [with darker brown onions like this](https://www.chinasichuanfood.com/scallion-oil-noodles/), which allows me to store it even longer.

Comment: I have never thought about this and I think you are right, I will give this a try for sure, thank you